# Homebrew package manager taps fatal error

Tags: ios, terminal, homebrew, package-management

I was updating and upgrading Homebrew and I saw this error message: does anyone know what shall I do?

```
==> Pouring imagemagick-7.0.10-31.catalina.bottle.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.10-31: 1,500 files, 29.6MB
Removing: /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.10-30_1... (1,499 files, 25.7MB)
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/': transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
Error: Fetching /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core failed!
```

Then I proceeded to redo that and the message did not show up (see attachment and below). Instead, I got the following:

```
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core)
```

Thank you!

[image: homebrew-fatal-error]

Comment: Please show text as text not images. It is impossible to read

Comment: What does `brew doctor` say? And if it shows any issues, can you resolve them?

Comment: @nohillside I just ran it, thanks. Out of all warnings, this seems the most relevant:

`Warning: Homebrew's sbin was not found in your PATH but you have installed
formulae that put executables in /usr/local/sbin.
Consider setting the PATH for example like so:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc`

Comment: That's easily fixed, but I don't see how this relates to your download problem. And I assume Imagemagick isn't upgraded yet.

Comment: @nohillside thank you. Is it maybe some script in homebrew-core that needs be updated or Imagemagick that cannot properly access that? When I ran the command afterwards I got the tap `homebrew/core` updated, so I guess it was solved immediately after (I edited the post to make it more evident, thank you @mmmmmm for the patience).